# Tinymce - images_upload_handler - Remove Image from Editor if Image exceeded the maximum size

Tags: reactjs, tinymce-5

```
images_upload_handler: function (blobInfo, success, failure) {
                    var image_size = blobInfo.blob().size / 1000;  // image size in kbytes
                    var max_size   = 10               // max size in kbytes
                    if( image_size  > max_size ){  
                        setIsMaxSizeUploaded( true )       
                        failure('Image is too large( '+ image_size  + ') ,Maximum image size is:' + max_size + ' kB');
                        return;      
                    }else{
                        setIsMaxSizeUploaded( false )    
                        // Your code
                    }
                  },
```

I want to remove the uploaded image from the editor as the uploaded image size is large than the max size.

Stop Image from uploading
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add the following statement, before the return in your if statement:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.undoManager.undo();
```

This will remove the image.

Answer (score 0):

```
var elem = document.getElementById(input);
if(("File Size",elem.files[0].size / (1024)<10)
{
}
else
{
 document.getElemtById('img_element').src=''
}
```